# How to filter from struct in swift

Tags: swift, struct, filter, uisearchbar

Response Data Json format

```
[
 {
   "STOCK": "20 Microns Ltd. EOD Prices",
   "CODE": "BOM533022"
 },
 {
   "STOCK": "3i Infotech Ltd. EOD Prices",
   "CODE": "BOM532628"
 },
 {
   "STOCK": "3m India Ltd. EOD Prices",
   "CODE": "BOM523395"
 },
 {
   "STOCK": "7seas Technologies Ltd-$ EOD Prices",
   "CODE": "BOM590116"
 },
]
```

Model Class SearchPortfolioModel

```
import Foundation

typealias searchPortfolioModel = [SearchPortfolioModel]

struct SearchPortfolioModel: Codable {
    let stock, code: String    

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case stock = "STOCK"
        case code = "CODE"
    }
}
```

PortfolioViewModel

```
func stockCodeValue(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    portfolioClient.fetchSearchPortfolio(){ searchPortfolioModel in
        self.searchPortfolioModel = searchPortfolioModel
        completion()
    }
}

struct PortfolioSearch{

    var stockName: String
    var stockCode: String
}

func portfolioSearchForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> (SearchPortfolioModel){

    let stockName = searchPortfolioModel?[indexPath.row].stock ?? ""
    let stockCode = searchPortfolioModel?[indexPath.row].code ?? ""

    return SearchPortfolioModel(stock: stockName, code:stockCode)
}
```

Inside ViewController Class Added UITableView & UISearchBar.
How to search the data from UISearchBar based on the provided response.
In ViewController whole parse data displayed into tableview

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }
//        return data.count;
        return portfolioViewModel.numberOfItemsInPortfolioSearchSection(section: section)
    }

    func configurationNewsCell (cell: AddPortfolioTableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath){
        let searchPortfolioStocks = portfolioViewModel.portfolioSearchForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)

// Filtered data for stock & code need to will update based on search string.
        if(searchActive){
         cell.lbl_PortfolioStockName?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
         cell.lbl_PortfolioStockCodeName?.text = searchPortfolioStocks.code

        } else {
            cell.lbl_PortfolioStockName?.text = searchPortfolioStocks.stock
            cell.lbl_PortfolioStockCodeName?.text = searchPortfolioStocks.code

        }
    }
```

UISearchBar Delegate Method.

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

      filtered = searchPortfolioStocks.filter{ $0.stock.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }

        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.tbl_PortfolioSearch.reloadData()
    }
```

I want to search it with based on stock & code name!

Comment: You don't need to use `NSString` to perform a case-insensitive compare.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated my question in order to put it correct way for understand.

Comment: And what is wrong with the current code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Its now working! I failed to pass proper data type to filtered data [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need [localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412098-localizedcaseinsensitivecontains) method to filter stocks.

```
filtered = searchPortfolioStocks.filter {
    $0.stock.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) || $0.code.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
}
```